# Access FE SQL BE ODBC Call Failed and Object Invalid or No Longer Set with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm using Access 13 frontend with a SQL 2012 backend.  I call a stored procedure from Access using the below code and receive the message 'ODBC Call Failed'.  After that I then receive the message 'Object Invalid or No Longer Set'  The strange thing is, it returns the correct data from SQL server then produces the error.  When I click ok, I can continue to call the SP without any further errors until Access is closed\re-opened.  Below is my VBA code (in debug it produces the error on: `Set Me!lstItems.Recordset = rs`

Also, if connected on the network, it works fine, if connecting via a VPN, the error occurs.  We have checked everything we can on the VPN to no avail - any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdSearch_Click_Error

If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Then
MsgBox "Please enter a value to search", vbInformation
Else

DoCmd.Hourglass True
Set CN = New ADODB.Connection

CN.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXXXXXXXXXX;Database=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=YES;"

CN.Open
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = CN
        .CommandText = "dbo.PVXSearch"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set prm = .CreateParameter("@Search", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50)
    prm.Value = Me.txtSearch
    .Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Execute

  End With

   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   With rs
       .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .Open cmd
    End With

    Set Me!lstItems.Recordset = rs

    Me.lstItems.Requery

    Set prm = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing


    DoCmd.Hourglass False

End If
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
cmdSearch_Click_Error:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure cmdSearch_Click of VBA Document Form_frmWebOrder - Please take a screenshot and email XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
End Sub
```

Comment: you are executing command and then assigning parameter value. what logic is that? (ps: executing cmd will return recordset)

Comment: well spotted - must of been a copy and paste error.  amended, but still same error.